# Asp.NET MVC cookie not persisting data when accessed remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an issue with my asp.net MVC project, I am using cookies to persist  user’s data
I use the following code to set cookie after successful login:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string username,string password)
    {

        User user = db.Users.Where(t => t.username == username && t.password == password).SingleOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {

            HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
            aCookie.Values["username"] = username;
            aCookie.Values["role"] = user.role.ToString();
            aCookie.Values["UserID"] = user.UserID.ToString();
            aCookie.Values["route"] = "AdminReports";
            aCookie.Secure = false;
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);

            isLogedIn = true;
            return RedirectToAction("AdminReports", "Home");
        }
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Wrong username or password!";
        return View();
    }
```

I Read the cookie using this code :

```
public ActionResult AdminReports()
    {




        Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["cookie"]["username"]));
       // Response.Write(Request.Cookies["cookie"]["username"]);


        if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["cookie"]["role"]) == (int)Enums.Role.Admin)
            {

                return View();
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["cookie"]["role"]) == (int)Enums.Role.The70Hospitals)
            {

                return View("The70Hospitals");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["cookie"]["role"]) == (int)Enums.Role.The380Hospitals)
            {

                return View("The380Hospitals");
            }
            else
            {                  
                return View("LoginView");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("LoginView");
        }
    }
```

However the cookies lose its data which prevent the user to login. This case happens when I access the project remotely. However it works fine locally in the development mode and it runs normally also when I browse from the IIS (Run locally in the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your web.config file,

You can do some cookies settings in `<system.web>` section

```
<httpCookies domain="" httpOnlyCookies="true|false" requireSSL="true|false" />
```

use the `System.Web.HttpCookie.HttpOnly` property

Hope this helps.